# Replace() function for Column value in DataTable Select method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, datatable

I am trying to compare and select rows from a datatable based on the column value of another datatable within a foreach loop -

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
{
   DataRow[] result = dt2.Select("[Company Name] = '" + dr["Named Company"].ToString() + "'");
}
```

Now, the issue is the company names in both the Datatable for the same company may vary as in one may have a hyphen while other may not.

How do I include the clause to ignore the hyphen in both [Company Name] and dr["Named Company"].ToString(). I know the latter may use .Replace('-',' ') but how do I do the same for [Company Name] in the query? any alternative to this approach otherwise?

Comment: Please, share your tables and example data

Comment: I like using a join :             var query = (from dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                         join dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on dr1.Field<string>("Named Company").Replace("_","") equals dr2.Field<string>("Company Name").Replace("_","")
                         select new { dr1 = dr1, dr2 = dr2}
                         ).ToList();

Comment: Eg: The datatable dt1 may have a company ABC-XYZ Ltd. and the datatable dt2 may have the same company name as ABC XYZ Ltd. I want to match both of them.

Comment: @jdweng: I do not want to join the tables, just want to check the criteria and some other operation.

Comment: The code doesn't join the tables.  Just creates a mapping between the two tables so you can check the criteria.

Comment: Are you using LINQKit to get dynamic LINQ? Why are you using `Select` to filter, you should use `Where` for that.